# Show that $\cot{B}=6-\sqrt{3}$?

Tags: trigonometry

Write the expansion of $\sin(A+B)$. It is given that in a triangle ABC,  $\angle C=30^\text{o}$, $\sin{A} =3\sin{B}$. Show that $\cot{B}=6-\sqrt{3}$.

**My try**

The reason they have asked us to write the expansion could be just to make use of it to substitution $A+B=180^\text{o}-C$ to ,
$\sin(A+B)=\sin{A}\cos{B}+\cos{A}\sin{B}$

which leads to,
$\sin(30)=3\sin{B}\cos{B}+\cos{A}\sin{B}$

How do I proceed? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect the $A$ and $B$ in $\sin(A + B)$ were not necessarily meant to be the same as the $A$ and $B$ in the triangle. In particular, note that since $\measuredangle C = 30^{\circ}$, then $A + B = 150^{\circ} \;\to\; A = 150^{\circ} - B$. Thus, from the given relation and using the sine expansion you provided, we get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sin A & = 3\sin B \\
\sin(150^{\circ} + (-B)) & = 3\sin B \\
\sin(150^{\circ})\cos(-B) + \cos(150^{\circ})\sin(-B) & = 3\sin B \\
\frac{\cos B}{2} + \frac{(-\sqrt{3})(-\sin B)}{2} & = 3\sin B \\
\cos B + \sqrt{3}\sin B & = 6\sin B \\
\cos B & = (6 - \sqrt{3})\sin B \\
\cot B & = 6 - \sqrt{3}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

Comment: Marvelous proof! thank you.